# GetTableSchema() inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: subsonic

trying to instantiate a Query in SubSonic using the below method (as it apparently does not require a trip to the DB like the other methods for constructing a Query object do), per Scott Kohl's excellent SubSonic documentation.  Problem is, the generated code defines this method as private - not public.  Is there a better way to do this?  Was the change made recently from public to private?  Why?

Thanks.

```
SubSonic.Query query1 = new SubSonic.Query(TradeBender.Item.GetTableSchema());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubSonic.Query is kinda outdated. Check out the SQLQuery class. Here's example code:

```
    Dim q As SubSonic.SqlQuery() = New SubSonic.Select().From("Table").Where("Field").IsEqualTo(1)

    ' Or

    Dim BookList As Generic.List(Of NorthWind.Data.Book) = New SubSonic.Select(). _
        From(NorthWind.Data.Tables.Book).Where("Field"). _
        IsEqualTo(1).ExecuteTypedList(Of NorthWind.Data.Book)()
```

Comment: Thanks Rick.  Can I ask: What is a good resource to use that contains the latest documentation for subsonic?  I am havign a hell of a time finding good documentation/Code samples that are current.  Also, is your code above from 2.2 or 3?

Comment: 2.1 or 2.2 I don't mess with 3 yet (or at least not much).
http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the new wiki that I'm trying to get built. It's not released fully yet - but getting there:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs